# How to bootstrap a node in chef using chef server REST API?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have a lot of experience with Chef using the `knife` command. Now I want to code and automate this process using Chef Server REST API instead of using the Knife tool. Is there any way I can use Chef Server REST API to booststrap nodes?

Comment: Knife is just a commodity CLI tool on top of the chef-server API, so just look at knife code ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the bootstrap system is run from knife itself, Chef Server is not directly involved at all and does not have that capability. This is important because the SSH credentials used to access the target server never leave your workstation.

Comment: Thanks for the response @coderanger.
Yes, I understand this. Workstation executes chef-client directly on the node. I am just searching for a way that I can use some API in code to bootstrap instead of knife command. Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: No, there is no API because Chef Server is not involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jenkins job which accepts node's username normally root,  root password, node fqdns, runlist etc where runlist can be optional. Jenkins instance should have a chef user, a service account  with access to chef server so the job can takecare of bootstrapping process instead of using knife bootstrap command from terminal